# Unparseable date while converting to timestamp

Tags: java

Can anyone please clear me, what does this exception mean:

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06.10.2013 00:00".

That was found such a date in file 06.10.2013 that cannot be parsed? must it be always 06/10/2013? I got it, when i convert `String[]` to `Timestamp` while reading file. But I have two formats in a file like 03/10/2013 and 03.10.2013, which must I use then, instead of this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");


                String[] temp = line.split(",");

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" );


                java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(temp[0]);

                java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(
                        parsedDate.getTime());
                for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {

                o.setTimestamp(timestamp);
```

i have default both of formats in my file 06.10.2013 15:00:00 and 06/10/2013 15:00:00

Comment: Could you add some code for context so that I may assist you.

Comment: If you've got two formats in the file, you should use two `SimpleDateFormat` objects, one for each format - or just replace "/" with "." in your text or vice versa, if you're sufficiently confident that you won't have the character elsewhere.

Comment: Change your `/`s to `.`s and you should be good to go

Comment: As people have suggested you can either have two SimpleDate functions for each format, or just modify the Strings, such as: **mm.dd.yyyy** and you want **mm/dd/yyyy** you can just do `String myDate = myDate.replaceAll(".", "/");`

Comment: @MikeStrobel that doesn't seem to be the case in this context.

Comment: True, I am simply assuming they will be using the format given in the quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an analysis on the `String` before naively try to parse it with your current `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
//check if the string to parse contains a dot
if (stringContainingTimestamp.contains(".")) {
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm");
} else {
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
}
//rest of the code...
```

Another option may be just replacing the dot char by slash using [`String#replace(char, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-):

```
stringContainingTimestamp = stringContainingTimestamp.replace('.', '/');
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
//rest of the code...
```

The choice is yours.